# How to hide selected option text in select box, Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, dropdown

I have this drop-down list of ethnicity.
What I want is when I select clear ethnicity it should not appear in select box, and like box should be empty.
How can i do that?

```
  <select
        #ethnicity
        [(ngModel)]="patient.Ethnicity"
        [class.text-dimmed]="!patient.Ethnicity"
        name="ethnicity"
        id="ethnicity"
        class="form-control input-underline input-lg ml-0">
          <option [ngValue]="null" disabled> Select </option>
          <option [ngValue]="null">Clear ethnicity</option>
          <option  value="Alaska-Native">Alaska Native</option>
          <option value="American-Indian">American-Indian</option>
          <option value="Asian">Asian</option>
          <option value="African-Americans">Black or African American</option>
          <option value="Hispanic">Hispanic or Latino</option>
          <option value="Jewish-Ashkenazi">Jewish - Ashkenazi</option>
          <option value="Jewish-Other">Jewish - Other</option>
          <option value="Native-Hawaiians">Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander </option>
          <option value="Other">Other </option>
          <option value="Unknown">Unknown </option>
          <option value="White-Caucasian">White or Caucasian</option>
      </select>
```

like when I select it, it appears like this

[image]

but what I want is,

[image]

here is my [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vz6hrx) 
clear ethnicity should show in dropdown but when i select it it should not show in select box like i shared screen shots

What should I do to solve this situation ? 
Thank you.

Comment: Please share your complete code on https://stackblitz.com. Thanks

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vz6hrx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle `change event` of select tag like this.

```
onChange(value) {
    if(value == 'Clear ethnicity'){
      this.Ethnicity = '';
}

<select
            #ethnicity
            [(ngModel)]="Ethnicity"
            [class.text-dimmed]="!Ethnicity"
            name="ethnicity" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)"
            id="ethnicity"
            class="form-control input-underline input-lg ml-0">
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clear-option-select

Comment: and also i have one little problem left 
when i add selected in option tag it does show as selected 
in short selected tag is not working in this dropdown

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is delete the value "Clear ethnicity" like I did below:

```
<option [ngValue]="null" [hidden]="clear.selected"></option>
```

Comment: thats what i am doing but clear ethnicity still showing in select box @pocketsofscene

Comment: then set ngValue to the string